# "Lei è molto simpatica" and then "Sì, lo è": why is "lo" correct?

Tags: pronouns

I'm italian but I haven't studied grammar in ages and now I barely know how to refer to grammatical elements. I tried to use the search function but without success and I decided to directly put the example in the title, please edit it if needed and please link me a similar question if already existing.

Basically I can't find an explanation for the use of a male pronoun to refer to a female person. For example, a dialogue between two people, A and B, talking about a female named Anna could be:

A: "Anna è molto simpatica!"
B: "Sì, lo è!"

and I am 99.99999% sure it is correct but I would like to know why it is correct.
Another example could be A and B speaking about a group of people:

A: "Loro sono molto simpatici!"
B: "Sì, lo sono!"

or also

A: "Noi siamo molto simpatiche!"
B: "Sì, lo siete!"

so I can see that "lo" just stays "lo" because it refers to the fact that Anna or the groups are funny, so "lo" is the "parte nominale" maybe? and the thing that got me confused is its placement in the sentence.

Any clue is appreciated, thanks! Please suggest proper tags also.

EDIT a friend found a solution: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/%C3%A8-una-domanda-interessante-s%C3%AC-lo-%C3%A8-o-la-%C3%A8/825 and in short "lo" is just a box that contains "something" and just stays "lo" but there are other examples in which the box is "la", and in some regional variants also the box is declined for female people: in the link you can find the tecnnical terms. Thank you!

Comment: Very interesting question (in fact, I am not able to give an answer or a hint).

Answer (score 4):

In this case, [*lo*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lo2/) is a clitic demonstrative pronoun. If proclitic it's written separately, if enclitic it's attached to the verb (the same as all clitic pronouns):

> Ho comprato un pianoforte nuovo, dove *lo* metto?
>
> Ho comprato un pianoforte nuovo, ma non so dove metter*lo*.
>
> Hai visto il disco che ho portato? Ascolta*lo* e dimmi che ne pensi.

The feminine form is *la* and the plural forms are *li* and *le*.

> Non trovo più le ciabatte. Dove *le* hai nascoste?
>
> Tu che sei più alto, vedi Irene? Sì, *la* vedo.
>
> Mi servono chiodi, dove *li* tieni?

However, when the reference is to something abstract, the form is *lo*: it is equivalent to *ciò*, but saying “Sì, è ciò” wouldn't be idiomatic. In your dialog it means “Yes, she is what you said about her”. In English you'd just repeat the verb: “Yes, she is”, but Italian wants a full predicate, not just the *copula*.

Answer (score 1):

Ne parla Serianni nel suo *Italiano*, nella sezione VII.43, in cui si è menzionato che il pronome *lo* può avere valore neutro e riferirsi a un'intera frase precedente. L'uso di questo pronome che se ne fa nelle frasi della domanda, però, è peculiare perché fa riferimento unicamente a una parte della frase precedente:

> Con i verbi *essere*, *parere*, *sembrare*, *divenire*
> («è avaro, anche se non lo sembra», «crederai
> che sia ingrato, ma non lo sono», ecc.), i puristi
> dell'Ottocento consideravano errato l'uso di *lo*
> – che in tal caso si riferisce non all'intera frase
> ma a una sua parte (nei due esempi citati, agli
> aggettivi *avaro* e *ingrato*) – e consigliavano o
> l'omissione pura e semplice del pronome («è
> avaro, anche se non sembra») o altri sostituti
> («è avaro, anche se non sembra tale»). Per la
> loro sensibilità il costrutto peccava di francesismo
> ed era grammaticalmente scorretto giacché
> *lo* andrebbe usato solo in funzione di
> complemento oggetto (cfr. VII.31). Ma fu facile
> obiettare (in particolare da parte di VIANI
> 1858: 511-513) che il tipo «lo è» è molto antico
> e soprattutto che l'uso della forma
> non soggettiva nel nome del predicato trova riscontro con
> altri pronomi personali («io non sono te», ecc.,
> cfr. VII.10) «senza che per ciò sia offesa la
> grammatica».